# Change files owner in debian package

Tags: bash, shell, unix, debian, post-install

I have a debian package with static files for a web application with root:root owner. After installing this package I need to change owner of all files for tomcat:tomcat, for example. I've read that this could be done by postinst script. However I don't how I can iterate over all files of package.

I think my script should look something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh    
set -e
USER="tomcat"

-- iterate over files    
    chown ${USER}:${USER} {current_file}
-- end iterate over files
```

I'll appreciate for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the find command:

```
find . -exec chown "${USER}:${USER}" {} +
```

This will change the permissions recursively starting from the working directory.

Comment: Working directory where files will be installed could contain other files which are not related to deb package. I can't change their owners. If there is a way to get a list of files contained package?

Comment: If you only want a single directory you can do `find directory ...`. Otherwise you could specify which files should be touched with the `-name` or the `-regex` options of the find command.

Comment: Merging you answer and comment I've completed my task. Thank you.